# How to handle input from switch in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm using express and I am completely lost how can I get input from switch,
I want to create something like real time application when I toggle the switch, something happens on the server side.
I use bootstrap so here is piece of html that I`m using

```
    <form action="/apps" method="post">    
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="Switch">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is my code in Node js

```
app.post('/apps', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Shit is working")
});
```

But nothing seems to happen when I toggle the switch.
I appreciate any response or help because I`m new at Node js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `<input>` needs `value` and `name` attributes:
2. You need to post the form which will send the form data to the server. For that you'll need a `<button>`.

Your form will look like:

```html
<form action="/apps" method="post">    
   <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <input value="batman" name="superhero" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="Switch">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

3. You need to capture the form data using the `name` attribute you set on the `<input>`. This will be parsed and added to the `req.body` object by Express and the `bodyParser` middleware like so:

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} )); //< Same a bodyParser.urlencoded
app.use(express.json()); //< Same a bodyParser.json
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Connected on port: ${port}`);
});

app.post('/apps', (req, res) => {
   const hero = req.body.superhero //< Will be 'batman'
   console.log("hero=", hero);
   console.log("mydata=", req.body);
   res.send({ superhero: hero });
});
```

4. Once you have these fundamentals nailed you can move on to sending your form using JavaScript with fetch/axios by binding an event listener to the checkbox so that a request is sent "behind-the-scenes" every time the checkbox is switched on or off.